# How to scrape source code of a page without clicking on expand button?

Tags: python, selenium

This particular website has a 'show more' button. To load more data from a table. But this data seems to be loaded at the start, because I can click on  it and expand the table even in offline mode.

Is there a way to scrape the whole source code in one go without clicking this button many times over in Selenium? Since it seems the entire table is loaded initially when the page is first loaded.

driver.get_source does not show the whole thing in this case, only what is visibly showing when opening the browser.

Using Python, Selenium with Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If indeed all the data is loaded at start, then it can surely be found by looking at the DOM (at the  tag or possibly any other tag containing the data). Easy way to do that is open up the console (F12) and use the inspect element tool provided by your browser

Now to answer your question, I'm going to scrape the data using BeautifulSoup, at the found location (tag).I've seen that scraping with Selenium is pretty similar with BeautifulSoup, so you might just get the concept

For example, your table resides in a div (having random attributes, let's say a class called 'randomclass'). The table tag is 'ul', and each entry is stored in a 'li', or specifically in a 'li'.text()

To select the div:

```
selected_div = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'randomclass'})
```

To select the table inside the div:

```
table = selected_div.find('ul')
```

To iterate through the table rows and manage data:

```
for li in table.find_all('li'):
        mylist.append(li.text())
```

Comment: the data is not visible when I open browser and do inspect. But when I kill my internet and click on 'show more' it does load more, and I can load the entire list without internet connection.

Comment: In that case, my answer wouldn't be valid anymore to your problem. Because that means the table is loaded later in background, by Javascript. BeautifulSoup doesn't adress Javascript scraping, but luckily for you Selenium does. You maybe need to look into the variables of the scripts loaded, and find where the data for the table resides. And after that scrape it

Comment: What function would I use? It would be possible to load the entire table without clicking 'load more' button 20 times (using selenium)?